# What event is fired when Mac is back from sleep?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, events, sleep

I am developing an app in Xcode on Mac and would like to know the event which is fired when the mac gets back from sleep.
AwakeFromNib doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found it:

```
- (void) receiveWakeNote: (NSNotification*) note
{
    NSLog(@"receiveSleepNote: %@", [note name]);
}

- (void) fileNotifications
{
    //These notifications are filed on NSWorkspace's notification center, not the default 
    // notification center. You will not receive sleep/wake notifications if you file 
    //with the default notification center.
     [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self 
                                                           selector: @selector(receiveWakeNote:) 
                                                               name: NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification object: NULL];
}
```

Comment: Two things: you want "nil" not "NULL" for your object, and you should format your answer to display your code as formatted code - it's pretty unreadable right now.  But good job answering your own question!

Comment: How can I properly format the code ? I don't know the tag required... Thanks !

Comment: Looks like Parag beat you to it. But in the future, look at the buttons in the editor. One of them is a pair of braces ("{}"). Use this to format a selected block of text as code.

Answer (score 16):

**For swift 3:**

```
func onWakeNote(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Received wake note: \(note.name)")
}

func onSleepNote(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Received sleep note: \(note.name)")
}

func fileNotifications() {
    NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(
        self, selector: #selector(onWakeNote(note:)),
        name: Notification.Name.NSWorkspaceDidWake, object: nil)

    NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(
        self, selector: #selector(onSleepNote(note:)),
        name: Notification.Name.NSWorkspaceWillSleep, object: nil)
}
```

**For swift 4:**

```
@objc func onWakeNote(note: NSNotification) {
    ...
}

@objc func onSleepNote(note: NSNotification) {
    ...
}

func fileNotifications() {
    NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(
        self, selector: #selector(onWakeNote(note:)),
        name: NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification, object: nil)

    NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(
        self, selector: #selector(onSleepNote(note:)),
        name: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IORegisterForSystemPower()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPMLib_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IORegisterForSystemPower).

> Connects the caller to the Root Power Domain IOService for the purpose
>   of receiving sleep & wake notifications for the system. Does not
>   provide system shutdown and restart notifications.

```
io_connect_t IORegisterForSystemPower (
    void *refcon, 
    IONotificationPortRef *thePortRef, 
    IOServiceInterestCallback callback, 
    io_object_t *notifier ) ;
```

Take a look at [Q:How can my application get notified when the computer is going to sleep or waking from sleep? How to I prevent sleep?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html)