# Detect in MacOS opening/closure laptops's lid

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications

How could I detect using code lid's opening or closure ?

Is there any kind of notification? For MacOS environment. Any code snippet would be appreciated.

I am editing this question because I am not interested in notifications sent when computer goes to sleep. I can force sleep from Apple menu. I would like to know notification when user closes/opens laptop lid.

Is anyone able to help me please

Thanks in advance

Comment: this google search "how to detect when lid closed macos" led me to this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22606/169711 and this led me to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1340/_index.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247710/what-event-is-fired-when-mac-is-back-from-sleep